# Ayuda con una validacion, renvio a otra pagina php

Tags: php

Necesito ayuda! tengo una validacion simple de una variable introducida por el usuario llamada *"codigo"* que tiene que consultar en la base de datos, (eso funciona), el problema es que Si el "codigo" existe en SQL debe enviar al usuario a *prevsecurtihost.php* pero **si no** coincide con ninguno debe de enviar al usuario a denegada.php o aparecer un mensaje de error no importa.

El problema esta en el bendito header, que si lo meto dentro del if, me dice el error "
*Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd3/530/13900530/public_html/conexion.php:1) in /storage/ssd3/530/13900530/public_html/redirigir.php on line 39*" **(y si para solucionarlo lo pongo al principio luego de session start, ya no valida nada y me abre, este bien o no el codigo de ingreso la pagina prevsecurtihost.php)**

ya agote todas las ideas que se me ocurrieron hasta incluso invente variables pero ni asi funciona.

login.php ---> abre session del usuario (con usuario y clave)
chacklogin.php---> valida session y envia a paneldecontrol.php
panel de control.php----> es donde el usuario ya registrado ingresa en una form de un solo input el "codigo" ese que solicito y luego preciona consulta para enviar eso al validador redirigir.php.
*redirigir.php---> es con el que tengo el problema luego de validar debe de enviar a prev.. o a deneg...
prevsecurtihost.php---> es a donde tiene que ir si el codigo coincide con el que hay en la base.
denegada.html---> o el mensaje simple de que no es correcto (mucho mejor si es asi) es el que tiene que aparecer si no coincide.

redirigir.php

```
    <?php
session_start();



$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

$link = $nombre.'.php';

$_SESSION['id'] = $nombre; 

//$ok = header("location: prevsecurityhost.php");

//$no = header("location: denegado.html");

include 'conexion.php';


 $conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);


 if ($conexion->connect_error) {
 die("La conexion falló: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

 $buscarcodigo = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name
 WHERE codigo = '$_POST[nombre]' ";

 $result = $conexion->query($buscarcodigo);

 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);





 if ($count == 1) {

    header("location: prevsecurityhost.php");

 }
 else{

echo 'datos incorrectos a sido expulsado del sistema' ;

?>  
<p> </p>

    <html> <img src="denegado.jpg"  style="max-width:100%;width:auto;height:auto;" /> </html>
<p> </p>

<a href=logout.php><button type="button" class="btn btn-success"> Cerrar Sesion</button></a>
<p> </p>
<?php



}

?>
```

prevsecurityhost.php

```
 <?php

session_start();


header( "refresh:9;url=encoderbanswichof.php" );



if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {

} else {
   echo "Inicia Sesion para acceder a este contenido.<br>";
   echo "<br><a href='login.html'>Login</a>";
   echo "<br><br><a href='index.html'>Registrarme</a>";
   header('Location: http://localhost/login/login.html');//redirige a la página de login si el usuario quiere ingresar sin iniciar sesion


exit;
}

$now = time();

if($now > $_SESSION['expire']) {
session_destroy();
header('Location: http://localhost/login/login.html');//redirige a la página de login, modifica la url a tu conveniencia
echo "Tu sesion a expirado,
<a href='login.html'>Inicia Sesion</a>";
exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-image: url("img/fondo.png");  }

/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
    position: relative;
}

img.avatar {
    width: 20%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
    padding: 16px;

}

span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: block; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    padding-top: 60px;


}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */

}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Agregando efecto Zoom */
.animate {
    -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
    animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
    from {transform: scale(0)} 
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
       display: block;
       float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div id="id01" class="modal">

  <form class="modal-content animate" action="checklogin.php" method="post">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&nbsp;</span>

        <div align="middle"> <script src="https://cdn.onlymega.com/ckasy6kg2000as0pd7e3amfaq/embed.js?bnTag=" style="max-width:100%;width:auto;height:auto;" async></script> </div>


    </div>




      <p>.   </p>
       <p>   </p>

<?php
       $_SESSION['id'];

 ?>




      <label for="uname"></label>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Verifica que en `include 'conexion.php';` no se esté imprimiendo nada en el navegador. Intenta también pegando el primer `<?php` al margen del documento. Esos espacios en blanco tambień cuenta como impresión HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Puesdes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```html
<?php
session_start()
if(isset($_SESSION["id"]))
{
//tu codigo
}
else
{
header("location:http://localhost/login/login.html");
}
?>
```

Recuerde que header() debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde PHP. Es un error muy común leer código con funciones como include o require, u otro tipo de funciones de acceso de ficheros que incluyen espacios o líneas en blanco que se muestran antes de llamar a la función header(). Sucede el mismo problema cuando se utiliza un solo fichero PHP/HTML.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero mi problema está en el código redirigir.php el primer código. En el header. Intente ponerlo primero pero al hacer eso no valida si el código (id) existe o no. Me manda directamente a la location prevsecurityhost.php en ese archivo para que no través la validación y de error si no existe ese código en la base de datos donde o cómo tendría q poner el codigo de programación para que envié a esa página prevsecurityhost.php si existe y sino diga q no existe?